# Pause and Resume an Animation in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'd like to create a Powerpoint game where the player's avatar moves closer and closer to the edge of a cliff with each wrong answer.

I have used a motion path animation to go from the far left to the far right of the slide and am able to pause the animation by using the # keys. I need to flip back and forth between the question slide and the cliff slide. Flipping back to the cliff slide the animation resumes but the music no longer plays and an accidental click of the mouse sends the animation to its end point.

Is there a way in VBA to program a motion path and pause and resume buttons? I haven't found anything on the web so I am thinking it is not possible. Using Powerpoint 365. Any suggestions welcome. ty

Comment: You're correct, it's not possible. Instead, create many small animations toward the cliff edge, then trigger each in succession.

Comment: Thanks for your reply John and confirming my suspicions. I will see if I can make something user friendly. Cheers.